# AZURE VM: Browser times out when trying to connect to web service

Tags: azure

I set up an AZURE VM with a web service : 168.62.186.103 and 100.74.218.25 are what the VM shows as my public and private IPs, respectively.

Running a browser on the VM, I get a response for localhost

But, from my home machine, I get ‘connection timed out’ for all of andsrv.cloudapp.net and 168.62.186.103 and 100.74.218.25.

All URLs point to port 8080.

I tried disabling the VM’s Windows’ firewall and / or enabling port 8080 (TCP & UDP) via firewall rules. This did not fix the issue.

Any suggestions what needs to be done to enable public access to the VM's web service ?

Thank you in advance, 
- gs

Comment: minor comment: i am limited in my abiliity to post URLs in above post .... but all browsers were pointed to http://<ip>:8080/  .... thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open public endpoints for you VM. You can use Azure portal. See my answer on a similar post below

> Navigate to Azure Portal >> Virtual Machines >> Select VM >> Endpoints
>   Tab >> Add Endpoint HTTP (Port 80) and Custom Port 8080.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684045/network-connectivity-issue-with-azure-vm/31684315#31684315